# What preposition to use when fitting data?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, data-analysis

Please could some real experts give an opinion on this question on English.SE: [What preposition to use when fitting data?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79467/what-preposition-to-use-when-fitting-data)

> Do we fit data **with**, **by**, or **as** a linear function?

---

*Forgive me as I do not know how best to highlight this and I'm happy for this question be be deleted.*

Comment: By analogy: "Data" is a person with *fixed* size. "Function with adjustable parameters" is a suit. Does the tailor fit the suit *to* the person, or fit the person *to* the suit?

Comment: @Jen, with the last option, you've heard of Procrustes? :)

Comment: we fit data on behalf of a linear function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One does no such thing. One fits a linear function to data, not the other way around. Unless of course one is inventing "data" that will nearly fit a preconceived pattern, a practice not entirely unknown in Science.

Comment: The last sentence is true, funny, and depressing all at the same time...

Comment: Applied Ramsey theory...